# Checking if elements in a vector corresponding to variable names are of character class in dataframe

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to build a safety catch for my function.
I'd like it to take an input of a data frame, and a vector of variable names to check the class of. I'd like it to attempt to coerce any variable that fails to character, send a warning, or if coercing fails, stop the process.

This is what I've got so far:

```
#Inputs
varlist <- c("varA","varB","varC")
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=4,nrow=0, dimnames=list(NULL, c("varA", "varB", "varC","varD"))))
df$varA <- as.character(df$varA)
df$varB <- as.character(df$varB)
df$varC <- as.factor(df$varC)
df$varD <- as.numeric(df$varD)

for(i in 1:length(varlist)){
   if(!(purrr::pmap(select(df, varlist[i]), ~is.character)==TRUE)){
        df$varlist[i] <- as.character(df$varlist[i])
        warning(paste0("Coercing variable", varlist[i], "to character"))
        stopifnot(is.character(df$varlist[i]))
 } 
}
```

However, this fails,

```
Error in if (!(purrr::pmap(select(df, varlist[i]), ~is.character) == TRUE)) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

**Expected Output**

```
#output console warning
Warning: Coercing variable varC to character

#Manual checks
is.character(df$varA) == TRUE #included in varlist
is.character(df$varB) == TRUE #included in varlist
is.character(df$varC) == TRUE #included in varlist, coerced from factor to character
is.character(df$varD) == FALSE #not included in varlist
```

Comment: Your example show `df` with 0 rows..  What is your expected output

Comment: @akrun updated question to include console warning and positive checks.

Answer (score 0):

I've got something that I think would work in a for loop. If your dataframe is quite large and has a lot of columns, there is a way to apply it to speed it up, but this more closely matches what you originally had.

Make data

```
varlist <- c("varA","varB","varC")
df <- data.frame(varA = letters[1:4],
                 varB = letters[11:14],
                 varC = letters[21:24],
                 varD = 1:4)
df$varA <- as.character(df$varA)
df$varB <- as.character(df$varB)
df$varC <- as.factor(df$varC)
df$varD <- as.numeric(df$varD)
```

I haven't added a manual Error for if `as.character` fails because that function will do it on its own.

```
    for(i in (1:ncol(df))[colnames(df) %in% varlist]){
    df[,i] <- as.character(df[,i])
  if(!(is.character(df[,i]))){
    warning(paste("Coercing variable", colnames(df)[i], "to character"))
  }
}
```

**Using `Map`**

Update to do the same thing using `Map` which is the multivariate version of `apply`:

```
char_function <- function(x, name){
  y <- as.character(x)
  if(!(is.character(x))){
    warning((paste("Coercing variable", name, "to character")))
  } 
  return(y)
}

df.char <- data.frame(Map(char_function, df[varlist], names(df[varlist])), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

For a dataframe with 4 columns and 2600 rows, the for loop took 0.015 sec and `Map` took 0.012 sec. Depending on the size of your dataframe, it may be worth using `Map`

Comment: Map is usually for iterating over things in parallel. You're sort of doing that because you are iterating over the columns and the column names, but that's not really needed. (Also, `as.character` is smart enough to not do anything to things that are already `character`----you don't need to create a wrapper for that.) You can use `lapply` directly with `df.char = data.frame(lapply(df, as.character), stringsAsFactors = F)`, or if modifying in place `df[] = lapply(df, char_function)`. This plays nicely with OP's `varlist`, `df[varlist] = lapply(df[varlist], as.chararacter)`

Comment: oh, I had completely missed that the OP only wanted to check certain variables that were in `varlist`. I wrapped the function so that it will return the warnings that the OP wanted. Not sure how to do that without writing a function that explicitly includes it. But I'll edit the response to include your comments